# How to remove the project name and replace with icon on the navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, menu, icons

I need a customize menu with an icon and 3 navigation buttons. I have already created 3 buttons but I could not replace my project name which is SMILE in here and replace with a icon in my customized navigation bar.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, put it in `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

and you can change label from manifest or use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("")` to make title blank

Answer (score 0):

Just add like this in your manifest of navigation drawer

Comment: Just add like this in your manifest of navigation drawer

<activity android:name=".Home"
android:label=" "/>

Comment: remove the < /> and use `  `  in your answer